# how to make eslint diable file path includes uppercase letter?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Now some files in the project are named in camel case, such as "globalStore". But according to the team specification, it should use "global-store". I want to check the import part of the code through eslint. When it contains uppercase letters, it prompts. How should I complete it?

I tried using the "patterns" of "no-restricted-imports", but no matter how I configured it, it didn't work.

Comment: Could you provide your `no-restricted-imports` configuration which didn't work?

Comment: "no-restricted-imports": [
        "warn",
        {
          "patterns": [
            {
              "group": ["[./[A-Z]", "@/pages/components/[A-Z]", "@/pages/utils/[A-Z]"],
              "message": "不允许有大写字母1123456789"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]

Comment: Did you try [caseSensitive option](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports)?

Comment: yes, I try this. But when I config like: [a-z][A-Z]*. ESlint gives error to me. It must  have prefix with [A-Z], but I don't want any prefix, because there were too many prefix in the project, I just want to match uppercase letters and give user a wanning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give warning every time uppercase letter is used in import path, you could use this rule configuration:

```json
{
  "no-restricted-imports": [
    "warn",
    {
      "patterns": [
        {
          "group": ["*[A-Z]*"],
          "caseSensitive": true,
          "message": "Using uppercase letters in imports is not allowed"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

```js
// warn
import SomeComponent from 'module/components/SomeComponent';
import { someUtils } from './AnotherComponent.utils';

// valid lines
import SomeComponent from 'module/components/some-component'; 
import { someUtils } from './another-component.utils';
```

Comment: I used this config, but some path didn't have uppercase letters are matched. e.g: @/components/grey-description, mobx-react-lite

Comment: even import React from 'react' also get matched. T.T

Comment: For me these examples are not matched. What TypeScript and eslint versions you use?

Comment: ESlint7.32.0, typescript4.2.3. what versions you use? I can try upgrade.

Comment: typescript@4.9.3, eslint@8.28.0

Comment: It make sense with eslint@8.x. Thank you!